# submitting value of textarea on enter key

Tags: jquery

Right now I have this flow in jquery:

```
$('input#search').click(function(){
        $('textarea#people').fadeIn();
        $('input#searchpeople').fadeIn();
        $('input#add').hide();
        $('input#search').hide();
    });

$("#searchpeople").click(function(){
    var people=$("textarea#people").val();
    $.post("searchpeople.php",{people:people},function(result){
     $("div.callback").html(result);
    });
  });
```

My simple question is, instead of having the user having to click the search button, the button would automatically click when the user presses the enter key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to do the following...

1. On keypress of textbox, check for 'Enter Key'(Key code of enter is 13)
2. If so, call button click function

[Demo can be found here](http://jsfiddle.net/mraufk/DU5X5/1/)

```
    $('input#search').click(function(){
            $('textarea#people').fadeIn();
            $('input#searchpeople').fadeIn();
            $('input#add').hide();
            $('input#search').hide();
        });
    $('input#search').keypress(function(){
       if($(this).keyCode == 13)
       {
           Search();
       }     
    });

    $("#searchpeople").click(Search);


    function Search()
    {
        var people=$("textarea#people").val();
        $.post("searchpeople.php",{people:people},function(result){
         $("div.callback").html(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use keydown event instead of click event: http://api.jquery.com/keydown/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of handling clicks *and* key presses, you can just use a `form` and handle the `submit` event:

```
<form>
    <textarea id="people"></textarea>
    <input id="search" type="submit" />
</form>

<script>
    $('form').submit(function () {
        // do stuff
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There's no way to submit when you focus inside the textarea